# What is the geom_type at CreateLayer() in ogr for xyz-GeoJSON?

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr

My GeoJSON-File is a Multipolygon which creates several triangles with a X, Y and Z coordinate. Z determines the height of the specified point for X/Y.
If i try to render my GeoJSON into a shapefile by Pythan and ogr, I have to tell the CreateLayer-Function a geom_type. I've fond only Point, Line, Polygon and MultiPoint, MultiLine, and MultiPolygon. 
MoltiPolygon ignores the values of height.
Is there any specification to tell the ogr in Python, that I have a MultiPolygonZ source where the height needs to be stored into the shapefile, as well?

My curent line here is:

```
layer = ds.CreateLayer(concenate, srs, geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)
```

This works, but the resulting shapefile has no values to the height of the points.

Comment: Perhaps autotest suite gives some useful examples https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_shape.py.

Comment: There is a ogr.wkbMultiPolygon25D geom_type. Maybe that works?